# How to use Rest Get Annotation for application/x-octet-stream Accept header

Tags: java, http, rest, get, restlet

I want to be able to invoke a certain method depending on the `Accept` type in the header of the GET request.  Currently, I have the following in my resource class:

```
import org.restlet.resource.Get;

@Get("json")
public Representation getJson(Variant variant) throws Exception{
    return new StringRepresentation("json");
}

@Get("xml")
public Representation getXml(Variant variant) throws Exception {
    return new StringRepresentation("xml");
}

@Get("x-octet-stream")
public Representation getFile(Variant variant) throws Exception {
    return new StringRepresentation("octet-stream");
}
```

I can successfully invoke the methods `getJson()` and `getXml()` using an http GET with the `Accept` headers set to `application/json` and `application/xml`, repectively.  When I issue a GET with the `Accept` header as `application/x-octet-stream`, the `getJSon()` method is invoked instead of the method annotated with `x-octet-stream`.  Do you know why?  and/or how I can invoke the `getFile()` method?

Does Rest only allow you to use `json` and `xml` for method entry points?  Is there a list of recognized types?  I have looked on the site, but there is no said list of anything of that type.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the `@Get` Annotations look up the method in your Application's `MetadataService` object, using a 'file extension'.  See JavaDoc of this class (`addCommonExtensions()`) for the list of 'file extensions' supported by default.

As a default catch all media type neither application/octet-stream nor it's compressed version have a default mapping. however you are also able to add as many custom mappings and `MediaType` instances as you would like. I would usually do this as part of my Application set-up, for example:

```
public Application(final Context context)
{
    super(context);

    getMetadataService().addExtension("html", MediaType.TEXT_HTML, true);
}
```

For Completeness: If you are attempting to Download pre-generated files from Disc you may also be interested in looking at using the Directory class.

Comment: Yes, this works.  How did you know that this is the approach to take?  I'm not sure how I could have found that on my own research.

Comment: I Don't remember to be honest been I've working with restlet since version 1.1.x,  I think that this may have evolved, slightly with the library, since then. I have not looked too closely at the documentation in this area for a while.  The docs may not be evolving quite quickly enough to keep up.

Comment: javadocs: [Restlet MetadataService](https://restlet.com/open-source/documentation/javadocs/snapshot/gae/api/org/restlet/service/MetadataService.html)

* Sets the default language to Language.ENGLISH_US, the default encoding to Encoding.IDENTITY (no encoding) and the default media type to MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM. It also calls the addCommonExtensions() method.